# Integration by Parts: Product of Many Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

"Classic" integration by parts has two functions ($u$ and $dv$; $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$). What if there is a product of $n$ functions? In other words, what's the solution to the following?

\begin{equation}\label{eq:tosolve}
    F(x)=\int_{a}^{b}\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)\:dx
\end{equation}

[Wikipedia's integration by parts article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Product_of_many_functions) mentions this problem and offers an equation, but I think a few extra steps are necessary for a full solution. Wikipedia leaves us with the following product rule for $n$ functions:
\begin{equation}
\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)\bigg)'=\sum_{j=1}^{n}u_{j}'(x)\prod_{i\neq j}^{n}u_{i}(x).
\end{equation}

Integrating, this leads to

\begin{equation}\label{eq:onwiki}
    \bigg[\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)\bigg]_{a}^{b}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{a}^{b}u_{j}'(x)\prod_{i\neq j}^{n}u_{i}(x)\:dx
\end{equation}

The object we want to solve for (the RHS of the first equation at the top) does not appear in the expression immediately above. How does one recover it?

Comment: You can apply integration by parts taking $u = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i$ and $dv = u_n$

Comment: Could you complete the solution? I don't think I follow how to this leads back to $\int_{a}^{b}\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x) dx$.

Comment: See my answer below. By the way, it doesn't make sense to write $F(x)=\int_{a}^{b}\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)\:dx$. Either you want the function (indefinite integral) $F(x)=\int\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)\:dx$ or the quantity (definite integral) $\int_{a}^{b}\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)\:dx$

Answer (score 2):

Let $U_n$ denote an antiderivative of $u_n$. We have
\begin{align}
\int \prod_{i=1}^n u_i(x)\,dx &= 
\int \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i(x)\right)u_n(x)\,dx
\\ & = \int \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i(x)\right)U_n'(x)\,dx
\\ & = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i(x)\right)U_n(x) - \int \frac d{dx}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i(x)\right)U_n(x)\,dx
\\ & = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} u_i(x)\right)U_n(x) - \int \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}u_{j}'(x)\prod_{i\neq j}^{n-1}u_{i}(x)\right)U_n(x)\,dx.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @Ben; I posted another approach which I think is the same. Do you agree it is the same?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that I think returns the same result as the @Ben-Grossman's, but with a different route. Suppose we examine the sum over $n+1$ functions where the final $u_{n+1}(x)$ function equals $x$, such that $u'_{n+1}(x)=1$. We now have:

\begin{align}
\bigg[\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}u_{i}(x)\bigg]_{a}^{b} &= \sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\int_{a}^{b}u_{j}'(x)\prod_{i\neq j}^{n+1}u_{i}(x)dx \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{a}^{b}u_{j}'(x)\prod_{i\neq j}^{n}u_{i}(x)dx
+\int_{a}^{b}\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)dx
\end{align}

The $j=n+1$ term appears to be ``missing'' a $u'(x)$ term because this value is 1. A simple rearrangement yields:

\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}(x)dx=\bigg[\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}u_{i}(x)\bigg]_{a}^{b}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{a}^{b}u_{j}'(x)\prod_{i\neq j}^{n}u_{i}(x)dx
\end{align}
Note the LHS is what we wanted to solve for.